# How to group varchar Type columns in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have following Data :

[image: l]

I want to combine the rows having MY_Rank 1 with corresponding MY_Rank 2 on basis of Vehicle_No,Division ,so I am not getting how to group the data as there are NULL Values for the exit columns in MY_RANK=1 row and NULL Values for Entry columns in MY_RANK=2 row .

At the end I should have data like this  :

[image]

Please guide .

Comment: Use MAX with GROUP BY on the columns.

Comment: How to deal with SDF division which needs to be Output twice because if we group by then there will be only 1 row corresponding to it

Comment: @radha . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results seem to depend on the ordering of the rows.  Hence, it cannot be done with the data you have provided.  Perhaps there is another column that has ordering information.

Comment: Sir , u r right but there is no such column that is why I am stuck , either I have to change the ordering so that first 2 rows get rank as 1 , third and fourth rows get rank as 2 , fifth & sixth row get rank as 3 , then I can simply add the rank column in grouping ,is this approach rght ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
select vehicle_no, division,
       max(entry_station) as entry_station,
       max(entry_event) as entry_event,
       max(entry_leg_no) as entry_leg_no,
       max(exit_station) as exit_station,
       max(exit_event) as exit_event,
       max(exit_leg_no) as exit_leg_no
from t
group by vehicle_no, division
```

Comment: For the Division SDF , I want 2 rows but with  your logic , I am getting only one